# YouTube iframe API automatic pip on scroll

Tags: iframe, scroll, youtube, picture-in-picture

Does YouTube iframe API allows automatic picture-on-picture on scroll or not?

I tried my best and I was expecting it to go in automatic picture-in-picture mode when the user scrolls around 700px away from the video.

Here's a codepen of what I tried.
`zirwa_tulhuda/pen/eYQyYqg`